# How to fix footer at bottom by using table layout?

Tags: css

I have been trying to get a table layout with sticky footer for a long time. My requirement is the footer should fix at bottom while I will zoom in or zoom out. But when I zoom the webpage the footer will go to content part or another way it will fix at bottom but I could not see the left side of footer.

Comment: post your code (html and css) so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the coding in http://somacss.com/layouts/stickyfooter_table.html

i have pasted the same code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Layout: sticky footer table layout </title>

    <style type="text/css">
        html,body{height:100%;margin:0;}
        #container{
            table-layout:fixed;border-collapse:collapse;
            height:100%;width:100%;background:#FCD116;
        }
        #container td{padding:0;}
        /* ie 6/7 needs some top/bottom padding on footer for margin of children to show */
        #container #content, #footer{padding:1em;}

        #content{vertical-align:top;}
        #footwrap{vertical-align:bottom;}
        #footer{
            background:#555;overflow:hidden;
        }
        #content h1{text-align:center;}
    </style>
    <!--[if IE 7]>
    <style type="text/css">
        #footer{overflow:visible;}
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <table id="container">
        <tr><td id="content">
            <h1>sticky footer table layout</h1>
            <p>Puppies are better then kittens because they are more loyal and dumber and don't wake you up in middle of the night. But kittens are better because they are cuter and go outside to pee.</p>
            <p>Puppies are better then kittens because they are more loyal and dumber and don't wake you up in middle of the night. But kittens are better because they are cuter and go outside to pee.</p>
            <p>Puppies are better then kittens because they are more loyal and dumber and don't wake you up in middle of the night. But kittens are better because they are cuter and go outside to pee.</p>
            <p>Puppies are better then kittens because they are more loyal and dumber and don't wake you up in middle of the night. But kittens are better because they are cuter and go outside to pee.</p>
            <p>Puppies are better then kittens because they are more loyal and dumber and don't wake you up in middle of the night. But kittens are better because they are cuter and go outside to pee.</p>
        </td></tr>

        <tr><td id="footwrap">
            <div id="footer">
                <p>This is a tables sticky footer. <br>We don't have to set its height.</p>
            </div>
        </td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```